# Razor page namespace conflicts with class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, namespaces, razor-pages

I have a razor page with a namespace like `MyApp.Pages.MyClass`.  Within this page cshtml I am trying to reference an enum in a class library with a namespace like `MyClass.Enums.MyEnum`.  I can't find a way to reference this enum type as using the fully qualified namespace (or trying to add a using clause) both result in a "Type or namespace does not exist" error because it is treating `MyClass.Enums.MyEnum` as relative to the current namespace `MyApp.Pages.MyClass`. Is there a way I can reference the enum type without renaming the namespaces involved?

Comment: you can add: ``using MyEnum = MyClass.Enums.MyEnum`` and use it in the html like ``MyEnum.Name``

Comment: That doesn't work because the using clause generates the same error- it is trying to resolve `MyClass.Enums.MyEnum` as relative to the current namespace because is starts with `MyClass` and the current namespace ends with `MyClass`.

Comment: yeah, i see, you can add the whole path?

Comment: Those ARE the whole paths.

Comment: Hi @MarkGuerrieri, any updates about this case?

Comment: So far short of renaming one of the namespaces I don't see any options, although I have yet to try the nested namespace suggestion.

Comment: @MarkGuerrieri any update since 2020?  I can't seem to find any info on this one but it's driving me crazy.  I really don't want to rename a huge namespace just to add a conflicting package...

Answer (score 0):

> I have a razor page with a namespace like `MyApp.Pages.MyClass`. Within this page cshtml I am trying to reference an enum in a class library with a namespace like `MyClass.Enums.MyEnum`.
>
> result in a "Type or namespace does not exist" error

Can reproduce same issue if we name the page model class as `MyClass`, not `MyClassModel`.

```
namespace MyApp
{

    public class MyClass : PageModel
```

In `MyClass.cshtml` page and error as below.

[image]

To fix it, you can rename your page model class, such as `MyClassModel` etc.

You can also try another approach to create and use a nested namespace, like below.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    namespace MyAppNestedNamespace
    {
        public class MyClass : PageModel
        {
            public void OnGet()
            {
                
                //...
            }

            //...
        }
    }

}
```

The MyClass.cshtml page may look like this:

```
@page
@model MyAppNestedNamespace.MyClass

@using MyClass.Enums

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyClass";
}

<h1>MyClass</h1>

@*your code here*@
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dereference to the global namespace:

```
    using MyEnum = global::MyClass.Enums.MyEnum
```